# Join two tables. Select all rows from one table and only matching values from other table?

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql

I have the following tables:

```
Locations
+-------------+----------------+
| Location_ID | Location_Name  |
+-------------+----------------+
|           1 | Administration |
|           2 | Parking        |
|           3 | Warehouse      |
|           4 | Shipping       |
|           5 | Factory        |
|           6 | Office         |
|           7 | Processing     |
+-------------+----------------+

Item_Quantity
+---------+-------------+-------------------+
| Item_ID | Location_ID | Location_Quantity |
+---------+-------------+-------------------+
|       1 |           3 |                10 |
|       1 |           5 |                50 |
|       2 |           3 |                 7 |
+---------+-------------+-------------------+
```

I am trying to get a list of all Location_IDs and Location_Names with the Location_Quantity for a specified Item_ID.

The expected result for Item_ID = 1 would be this:

```
+-------------+----------------+-------------------+
| Location_ID | Location_Name  | Location_Quantity |
+-------------+----------------+-------------------+
|           1 | Administration |                 0 |
|           2 | Parking        |                 0 |
|           3 | Warehouse      |                10 |
|           4 | Shipping       |                 0 |
|           5 | Factory        |                50 |
|           6 | Office         |                 0 |
|           7 | Processing     |                 0 |
+-------------+----------------+-------------------+
```

The expected result for Item_ID = 2 would be this:

```
+-------------+----------------+-------------------+
| Location_ID | Location_Name  | Location_Quantity |
+-------------+----------------+-------------------+
|           1 | Administration |                 0 |
|           2 | Parking        |                 0 |
|           3 | Warehouse      |                 7 |
|           4 | Shipping       |                 0 |
|           5 | Factory        |                 0 |
|           6 | Office         |                 0 |
|           7 | Processing     |                 0 |
+-------------+----------------+-------------------+
```

I have tried the following queries:

```
SELECT l.Location_ID, l.Location_Name, iq.Location_Quantity
FROM Locations l
LEFT JOIN Item_Quantity iq ON l.Location_ID = iq.Location_ID
WHERE iq.Item_ID = @Item_ID

SELECT l.Location_ID, l.Location_Name, iq.Location_Quantity
FROM Item_Quantity iq
LEFT JOIN Locations l ON l.Location_ID = iq.Location_ID
WHERE iq.Item_ID = @Item_ID

SELECT l.Location_ID, l.Location_Name, Location_Quantity = iif(iq.Location_Quantity IS NOT NULL, iq.Location_Quantity, 0)
FROM Locations l
LEFT JOIN Item_Quantity iq ON l.Location_ID = iq.Location_ID
WHERE iq.Item_ID = @Item_ID
```

All queries return only the rows with entries in Item_Quantity.

This is what I am getting for Item_ID = 1 for any of the above queries:

```
+-------------+----------------+-------------------+
| Location_ID | Location_Name  | Location_Quantity |
+-------------+----------------+-------------------+
|           3 | Warehouse      |                10 |
|           5 | Factory        |                50 |
+-------------+----------------+-------------------+
```

I would have thought a Left Join on the Locations table would give me all of the rows from the specified columns, but I must be understanding something incorrectly?

Can anyone see what I am doing wrong here?

Comment: Query 1 and 3: move `iq.Item_ID = @Item_ID` condition from `WHERE` to `ON`.

Comment: As @jarlh was pointing out your where clause has filtered out the rows which logically converts your left join to an inner join.

Comment: @jarlh Thanks!  You are both right, the where clause was preventing me from returning all rows from Locations.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The condition needs to go in the `ON` clause.  Otherwise, the `WHERE` clause turns the outer join into an inner join.

You also want to convert the `NULL` to a `0`, so use `COALESCE()`:

```
SELECT l.Location_ID, l.Location_Name, COALESCE(iq.Location_Quantity, 0) as Location_Quantity
FROM Locations l LEFT JOIN
     Item_Quantity iq
     ON l.Location_ID = iq.Location_ID AND iq.Item_ID = @Item_ID;
```

Comment: Gordon, why COALESCE() instead of IIF?

Comment: @bicycle_guy [`Coalesce`](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/language-elements/coalesce-transact-sql?view=sql-server-2017) is standard SQL for combining two or more nullable values. It returns the first non-null value, if any. There is no need to duplicate the functionality by using `iif`. Aside: Having a reference to an outer joined table in a `where` clause needs to allow for the possibility of NULLs. If you used `... where iq.Item_Id = @Item_Id or iq.Item_Id is NULL;` your query would have worked. It is common to place conditions like that in the `on` clause where NULLs are handled.